# webapi losing session value in cross domain with Angular app

Tags: .net, angular, session

I am using **webapi** as `SOA` to pass the data to **Angular6** "using different domain".
in **webapi** I am using the session to keep the information but it seems every request the session set to null.
"It's working perfectly if it's in the same domain, but not in a cross domains."

Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way "in my opinion" to keep the service isolated and keep track of the user is using the access token to authorize the user and keep sending data when the user sends the correct access token.
Below good article about how to use the Owin to generate the access token and how to pass it after the user authenticated.
https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/308/Token-Based-Authentication-for-Web-APIs